# Deploying a Java App (RMI Server) in Multiple Locations Automatically

Tags: java, deployment, rmi, capistrano

Well, like the title says, I want to launch the same java program on multiple locations remotely, say on the cloud (like EC2 or whatever). In my case the apps are the RMI servers but, I guess if I can do the former, I can do the later. I might have to copy certain files, or even the class files before the launch. Is Capistrano the best way to go, or is there something more Java for this sort of a thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE:  I am assuming you do not have any JVM running when you want to start things up.

The typical way to communicate with Unix-based servers (like Linux) is with ssh-clients which can execute commands on a remote server easily.  I believe Windows has a similar facility, but I am unfamiliar with it.

You will most likely want the actual management to be done by the operating system to make it more robust, so you just have to tell the OS to pull the service up and down.  For Windows that is through the SC.EXE command.  For Ubuntu that is with a /etc/init.d/foobar script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is automation possible with this scenario? With the push of a button deploy the classes (create the necessary directories), run the JVM with them, and kill when done. Are there ssh-clients that will do that sort of automation?

Comment: You can copy files over ssh-connections.  The easiest way to do so is with the `scp` command, or `rsync` (best for many files, or updates).  All the magic that will happen when you push the button, you _will_ need to wrap up yourself.  There is no magic bullet here.

Comment: You *can* however, have multiple commands in your push-button code: 1) rsync files over, 2) run "java -jar whatever.jar" and do not return until the program exits.  I would recommend first writing the RMI-server to get an understanding how things work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually wrote the server, and have been testing it by hand. But I am new to distributed computing, so it is not always easy to decide the best way to these things through Google. Again, your help was much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at Terracotta?  It might solve the problem you wrote the RMI server for in the first place.